# How to get the IP Adress in JS - Firefox Addon Devloment

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I am building a small custom Firefox Addon with regards to the [Firefox documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Browser_support_for_JavaScript_APIs#browserAction). Basically it uses javascript and can also use some Firefox JS Extension APIs. I am trying to get the browser IP adress from inside the extension, usually I would use a PHP script for that but here I think I am limited to this HTML and JAVASCRIPT combination, Any ideas about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
          var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      var url = "https://api.ipify.org/?format=json&callback=getIP";

  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      var myArr = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      var ip = myArr.ip;
       console.log(ip);
      
    }
  };
  xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
  xmlhttp.send();
```

you can use  HTTP Request for Getting IP  Add. of your client
https://api.ipify.org this website provides you the user ip address as a json object

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script>alert(window.location.hostname)</script>
```

in this case an alert will pop-up but the code is inside of it

Comment: Thanks for the answer but It doesn't work, it is giving me something like this :7ahg64a8-9ed8-46ff-9aba-941d99bc65bc which is not the ip adress.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/permissions , Strangely this odd number is the extension ID.